# Transposing Columns of One table to Row header of another table Oracle PL/Sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

All,

I have a table like this.

```
USER_ROLE_CODE  USER_ROLE
1               ADMIN
2               TESTER
```

(Dynamically expands)

Second Table is like this.

```
USER_CODE USER_NAME USER_ROLE_CODE
AA          AAA         2
BB          BBB         1
CC          CCC         1
```

(Dynamically expands)

Now I want my results to look like this.

```
 USER_ID  USER_NAME     ADMIN   TESTER
    AA         AAA       NA        X
    BB         BBB       x         NA
    CC         CCC       X         NA
```

It would be really helpful if you guys can help.

Comment: And your logic/rule is? And what are you trying to tell us with your contradicting tags, `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` both?

Comment: Also please include some code that you have tried and need help with.

Comment: Hi, I'm not an expert but a noob. I just had to tag something this being my first post.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Using a SP it is possible. But I wanna know if block of query can do the trick.

Comment: @MJEX Do you have more than 2 `USER_ROLE` values?